# Mysql server requires to explicitly state the database in the query

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-5.7

I am running mysql-client (Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19) and mysql-server versions 5.7.19 with user root from localhost on Ubuntu server 16.04.2 LTS.

I have noticed that mysql doesn't return the data I'm asking unless I explicitly specify the database in the query. I have replicated the behavior below over and over again.

Can someone please explain why this is happening ?

```
use db1;
select database();
    db1

select count(*) from users;
    145

select * from users;
    Empty set, 28416 warnings
select * from users;
    ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
```

The result is changing every time you run the query above.
One empty set, one Error2006, one empty set, one Error2006,...

```
show warnings;
    ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
show warnings;
    Warning 1287 'COM_FIELD_LIST' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SHOW COLUMNS FROM statement instead
```

There's 64 rows of this warning. I get Error2013 only the first time that I run "show warnings". There is no pause or delay.
All subsequent runs return the same 64 rows.

```
select * from db1.users;
```

This returns the full table (145 rows) with no problems whatsoever.

Comment: You can specify the default database on the mysql client command line if you don't want tu use `use`. Same is true for most connector libraries.

Comment: Are there any long pauses around the time when it "lost connection"?

Comment: 64 is the default limit on `SHOW WARNINGS`.  (Better than getting flooded with 28416 lines of output.)

Comment: Are there about 28416 rows in `users`?

Comment: You say the "client" is 5.7.19; please verify.  If using the command line tool, do `mysql --version`.

Comment: replied to the comments in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like 5.7.19 jumped the gun.

----- 2016-02-05 5.7.11 General Availability -- Functionality Added or Changed -- -----

> The mysql_kill() ( /doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-kill.html ), mysql_list_fields() ( /doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-list-fields.html ), mysql_list_processes() ( /doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-list-processes.html ), and mysql_refresh() ( /doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-refresh.html ) C API functions are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of MySQL. The same is true of the corresponding COM_PROCESS_KILL, COM_FIELD_LIST, COM_PROCESS_INFO, and COM_REFRESH client/server protocol commands. Instead, use mysql_query() ( /doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-query.html ) to execute a KILL ( /doc/refman/5.7/en/kill.html ), SHOW COLUMNS ( /doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html ), SHOW PROCESSLIST ( /doc/refman/5.7/en/show-processlist.html ), or FLUSH ( /doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html ) statement, respectively.

Recommend you post a bug with bugs.mysql.com .